# I want dynamic adjust a image in javascript how to do it?

Tags: javascript, image

my picture create by user and by js

```
var imgpre=document.createElement("img");
```

I want show in a box or `div` or `td` but sometime the `img` is so large.
I mean I don't know the image height and width, but I want put the image to 350*350 box. The image could not draw outside the box
the problem is sometime the image is 400*200, I set the `img.height=350`, it should ok to look at.
But sometimes the picture is 200*400, when you set `img.height=350` where is definitely wrong.

I could not get `img.height` in js, I tried but it return zero before I set it.

please note: I do not want tensile image.

Comment: do you wanna keep the aspect ratio?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got correct answer:

imgpre.setAttribute("style", "max-width:100%; max-height:100%;");

and also set the mzx-width:350 and max-height: 350 the box

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
imgpre.height = '100px';
imgpre.width = '100px';
```